# Remove white space from image

Tags: jquery, image, css

please take a look at this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/cX47v/1

I am simply trying to preserve the effect that you see, but i want to remove the white space below the image. I know about display:block, but if i do it, the hover effect does not work. Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Comment: Here's a short and complete answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the HTML to what I have below (adding the `style="font-size:0"`) fixes the issue in Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and Safari.  I've seen this issue before where a browser assumes one row of text as some extra height, even where there is no visible text.

```
<div class='fancy_image'>
    <div class='shadow' style='border:2px solid; float:left;padding:5px;margin:10px;'>
        <div style="font-size: 0;">    
            <img class='fade' src="http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/example.jpg" width=300 height=200  />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8FkmG/.  The remaining white space around the image is controlled by the padding in your HTML.

Overall, your HTML/CSS is really screwy here mixing float and positioning and doing positioning on a span.  Very odd.

Comment: both answers work great thank you guys :) It would be nice to know what css part is screwy also. I don't have any span or positioning in my example and if i don't use a float the effect will not work. Is there something the can be done better here ? Just out of curiosity, thanx for the solution anyway :)

Comment: Where did the javascript code come from?  Using different CSS for different browsers is not necessary for such a simple layout and is likely a maintenance headache.

Comment: ah you are talking about the javascript ? this is a ready made script so ok :P

Answer (score 1):

Set `line-height:0;` in your shadow div.

Answer (score 0):

just changes the .fade css class

```
.fade {font-size:0px;
    background: url('http://james.linnegar.com/demos/js/win7/hover.png');
}
```