# Removing white space from image on webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out why my image is in a box. I ran a little script that nulls out all the white space in my image, but when I try to use it on my site, my image has a white box around it.

I tried setting margin and padding to 0, I also tried setting the display to block, but still it persists, I appreciate any help, I'm sure this is simple, but I'm not a front end developer unfortunately (:

```
<div class="img_style">
  <a href="link" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
    <img src="imgSrc.png" style="block">
  </a>
</div>
```

Currently the css is empty, but after trying first comment, it looks like this:

```
#img_style {
  style="border: none !important";
}
```

[Remove white space from image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530066/remove-white-space-from-image)

[Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: you should show us "your" complete code, this being CSS also. And/or make up a jsfiddle

Comment: that ^ or see the answer given below. If that doesn't solve this, then... well... you'll need to resort to comment #1.

Comment: Currently that css class is empty. Why did you put quotes around "your"?

Comment: because, you left 2 links to other questions, only left some html but no css to support the question. Again; see the answers below; there's a new one now.

Comment: I added the css

Comment: `<img src="imgSrc.png" style="block">` isn't valid. `<img src="imgSrc.png" style="display:block;">` is.

Comment: ^ and developer console would have told you something about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue, my link styling was creating the unnecessary space, so I just removed that and it works, I didn't need to add any extra code.

Answer (score 2):

First remove style="block" in image tag! Its false. Read about class and id, Link this css to your page

First way

```
.img_style a{
    border: none;
}
```

Second Way

```
.img_style a{
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Third Way

```
.img_style img{
    margin : -10px -15px;
}
```

Comment: Should I have the a{ or img{ in the css?

Comment: for select with class names in css you should use [dot]ClassName like .img_style and css codes are in <style> tag or in an other file with css extention. If you have external css file should link it to html using link tag.

Comment: you a tag have a btn class. And btn class have this propertie: padding : 10px 15px; if you set padding to 0 your problem is solved, And you can pull image out with margin .. is not diffrent

Comment: I found the issue, it's with my styling for the link, thanks for helping!

Comment: In the end I didn't use what you added, not sure if I should just delete this question, but I wanted to give you credit, but not sure if your answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the border?

```
style="border: none !important"
```

Based on in-line styling**

Comment: I tried this, is my syntax incorrect? It's not working

#logo {
    style="border: none !important";
}

Comment: <img src="imgSrc.png" style="display: block; border: none !important;">

I have edited your inline style element this should work, the first comment given was on the assumption you was working in-line not from a CSS file have edited**